# Parsing HTML Content using BeautifulSoup & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
import re

driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2.get("http://www.squawka.com/match-results?ctl=10_s2015")

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver2.page_source)

print soup

driver2.quit()
```

I'm trying to get the HREF of every "td", "Class":"Match Centre" and I need to use selenium to navigate through the pages but im struggling to incorporate the two so I can change the menu options and navigate through the different pages while feeding the links into my other code.

I've researched and tried ('inner-html') and the page.source currently in the code, but it doesn't get any of the web links I need.

Does anyone have a solution to get these links and navigate on the page. Could there be a way to get the XML of this page to get all the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why would you need `BeautifulSoup` (BS) here. Selenium alone is capable of locating elements and navigating through links on a page. For example, to get all the links to the match details page you can do as follow :

```
>>> matches = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='match-centre']/a")
>>> print [match.get_attribute("href") for match in matches]
```

As for navigating through the pages, you can use the following XPath :

```
//span[contains(@class,'page-numbers')]/following-sibling::a[1]
```

The above XPath finds link to the next page. To navigate through all the pages, you can try using a `while` loop; while the link to the next page is found :

1. perform a click action on the link,
2. grab all the `href` from current page,
3. locate the next page link.